# How to split a string with dot?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have an NSString `string = @"abce20aa.fasgfh458sfs456456";`

How can I take `abce20aa` only into another string?

Comment: Have you already tried to mask the dot with backslashes? Something like '\.' or '\\.'

Comment: You know, `NSString` has excellent documentation. Can you read? If so, I'd suggest doing that with the docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [componentsSeparatedByString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString:):

```
[[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] objectAtIndex:0]
```

Answer (score -2):

**This can be done in this way:-**

```
string s = @"abce20aa.fasgfh458sfs456456";
 string d = s.Split('.')[0];
```